# gcp, pip is not installing libraries correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, pip, conda

[image: gcp]
I create a compute instance on gcp, installed conda, created a virtual environment.

But when I try to install any library with pip, nothing is working.

Even outside conda environment, the pip install is not working. It shows no error but no library can be imported.

```
...
Proceed ([y]/n)? y
...

Downloading and Extracting Packages
readline-8.1         | 362 KB    | ##################################################################### | 100% 
ncurses-6.2          | 817 KB    | ##################################################################### | 100% 
_openmp_mutex-4.5    | 22 KB     | ##################################################################### | 100% 
libgomp-9.3.0        | 311 KB    | ##################################################################### | 100% 
certifi-2021.5.30    | 139 KB    | ##################################################################### | 100% 
ca-certificates-2021 | 113 KB    | ##################################################################### | 100% 
ld_impl_linux-64-2.3 | 586 KB    | ##################################################################### | 100% 
libgcc-ng-9.3.0      | 4.8 MB    | ##################################################################### | 100% 
xz-5.2.5             | 341 KB    | ##################################################################### | 100% 
pip-21.0.1           | 1.8 MB    | ##################################################################### | 100% 
setuptools-52.0.0    | 710 KB    | ##################################################################### | 100% 
python-3.7.11        | 45.3 MB   | ##################################################################### | 100% 
sqlite-3.36.0        | 990 KB    | ##################################################################### | 100% 
openssl-1.1.1k       | 2.5 MB    | ##################################################################### | 100% 
libstdcxx-ng-9.3.0   | 3.1 MB    | ##################################################################### | 100% 
tk-8.6.10            | 3.0 MB    | ##################################################################### | 100% 
libffi-3.3           | 50 KB     | ##################################################################### | 100% 
wheel-0.37.0         | 32 KB     | ##################################################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate face
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

(base) zabiralnabil@face-test:~/Emotion-Investigator$ conda activate face
(face) zabiralnabil@face-test:~/Emotion-Investigator$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting Flask==1.1.2
  Using cached Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
  Using cached Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
Collecting matplotlib==3.3.3
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.6 MB)
Collecting opencv-python==4.4.0.46
  Using cached opencv_python-4.4.0.46-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (49.5 MB)
Collecting pandas==1.1.5
  Using cached pandas-1.1.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (9.5 MB)
Collecting Pillow>=8.0.1
  Using cached Pillow-8.3.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
Collecting tensorflow>=2.3.0
  Downloading tensorflow-2.6.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (458.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 458.3 MB 475 kB/s eta 0:00:01Killed
(face) zabiralnabil@face-test:~/Emotion-Investigator$ python
Python 3.7.11 (default, Jul 27 2021, 14:32:16) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
>>>
```

I'm using the conda version of `pip` and `python`.

```
(face) zabiralnabil@face-test:~/Emotion-Investigator$ which pip
/home/zabiralnabil/anaconda3/envs/face/bin/pip
(face) zabiralnabil@face-test:~/Emotion-Investigator$ which pip3
/home/zabiralnabil/anaconda3/envs/face/bin/pip3
(face) zabiralnabil@face-test:~/Emotion-Investigator$ which python
/home/zabiralnabil/anaconda3/envs/face/bin/python
(face) zabiralnabil@face-test:~/Emotion-Investigator$ which python3
/home/zabiralnabil/anaconda3/envs/face/bin/python3
(face) zabiralnabil@face-test:~/Emotion-Investigator$
```

Comment: You probably have either a collision of different pip installations or you are using the wrong pip version (pip versus pip3). Use the command **which** to determine if you are using the OS installed version of pip or the Conda version: :**which -a pip**. Check if your system has both Python2 pip and Python3 pip which is named pip3: **which -a pip3**.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I checked that already. I am using pip and python from conda.

Comment: You do not show the command that generates the output. Which pip are you using (pip or pip3). For Python 2x, use pip. For Python 3.x use pip3.

Comment: I have tried `pip, pip3, python -m pip, python3 -m pip`, all possible commands.

Comment: Well, when I tried `python3.7 -m pip` it seems to work. Why is that? In my conda environment, the default python should be 3.7.

Comment: I do not know as I have not used Conda for a couple of years. At least you have a clue to investigate.

Comment: Does your machine have a public IP?